# dynamic php table linked with MySQL that filters using multiple dropdown menu's

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, html-table

So I've made a dynamic PHP table linked with my MySQL database. Also i have linked the dropdown menu's (in total 4) with the database to get the values needed to filter. Only I don't know how to get the value i want from the dropdown menu to filter the table. is there a way to filter a table using dropdown menu's?

```
    function get_table(){
    if($_POST['sltInrichters'] = 'Maak je keuze'){
    $table_str='<table id="AgendaTabel">';
    $products=get_products();
    $table_str.='<tr class="Hoofding">';
    $table_str.='<th> Inrichter </th> <th> Onderwerp </th> <th> Plaats </th>';
    $table_str.='<th> Beginuur </th><th> Einduur</th><th> Eerste Sessie Datum </th>';
    $table_str.='</th>';
    foreach($products as $tabel){
        $table_str.='<tr class="'.$class.'">';
        $table_str.='<td>'.$tabel->Naam.'</td><td>'.$tabel->Artikel.'</td> <td>'.$tabel->Plaats.'</td><td>'.$tabel->Beginuur.'</td><td>'.$tabel->Einduur.'</td><td>'.$tabel->Datum.'</td>';
        $table_str.='</tr>';
    }
    $table_str.='</table>';
    return $table_str;
 } elseif(!$_POST['sltInrichters'] = 'Maak je keuze') {
    $table_str='<table id="AgendaTabel" visibility="visible">';
    $products=get_products();
    $table_str.='<tr class=Hoofding">';
    $table_str.='<th> Inrichter </th> <th> Onderwerp</th> <th> Plaats </th>';
    $table_str.='<th> Beginuur </th> <th> Einduur</th> <th> Eerste sessie datum </th>';
    $table_str.='</th>';

    foreach($products as $tabel){
        $table_str.='<tr class="'.$class.'">'
        $table_str.='<td>'./*THE VALUE NEEDS TO COME HERE*/'</td><td>'.$tabel->Artikel.'</td> <td>'.$tabel->Plaats.'</td><td>'.$tabel->Beginuur.'</td><td>'.$tabel->Einduur.'</td><td>'.$tabel->Datum.'</td>';
        $table_str.='</tr>';
    }
    $table_str.='</table>';
    return $table_str;
    } 

}
```

?>

QUERY $products

```
$query="SELECT DISTINCT a.*, b.Artikel, c.Sessie, d.Naam, c.Datum FROM TBLAgenda a
            JOIN TBLArtikelen b 
            ON a.ArtikelID = b.Id
            JOIN TBLAgendaDatum c 
            ON a.AgendaID = c.AgendaID
            JOIN TBLKlanten d 
            ON a.KlantID = d.
```

QUERY sltInrichters

```
$sqlInrichters="SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TBLKlanten ORDER BY Naam";
```

Comment: What does the drop down contains? what do you want to do? be more specific.

Comment: The dropdown menu contains the records of 1 table f.e. dropdown menu sltInrichters where all the names are listed. At first it will say 'Maak je keuze' (default choice) and shows the entire table. The purpose is if i change the select choice from 'Maak je keuze' to f.e. 'BORS' that the table only shows the information on BORS and leaves all the rest out.

Comment: is sltInrichters the dropdown name?

Comment: And where are the SQL queries

Comment: stlInrichters is name of the dropdown menu, also edited the post for the queries